# Why is the value of the pointer pointing at the 0th index of an array different from the actual 0th index of the array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, array-pointer

Python programmer here. I know just the basics about C but I was given the task of taking n entries in an array then creating a function that takes an array pointer as its argument, and then accessing the elements of the array that the pointer is pointing at.

A simplified version of my initial code was as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void func(int *pArr, int size){
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
        printf("%d ",*(pArr+j));
    }
}

int main(){
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of elements you want in your list: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int a[n];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        printf("Enter element no.%d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    func(&a[0], n);
    return 0;
}
```

Here my thought process was, since pArr is pointing at the 0th index of a, *(pArr+j) when j = 0 should just return *pArr which should just be the 0th index of a.

But to my surprise, the following is the output I got for a test run where a[5] = {1, 3, 9, 8, 2}

> 863014944 1 3 8 9

The program prints out a garbage value for *(pArr+j) when j = 0 but works fine after that. So I modified the code by initializing "j" with a value of 1 instead of 0 and changing the "<" to "<=" and surprisingly the program did run perfectly fine after those changes.

This is what puzzles me.

If I'm declaring a pointer *pArr pointing at the 0th index of an array a, i.e., *pArr = &a[0]; then shouldn't printing *(pArr+1) return the 1st index? Why is it that my program returns the 0th index instead? Why is *(pArr+0) not equal to a[0] when pArr is pointing at a[0]?

Comment: Look carefully at the `for (i = ` loop in your `main` function. Why do you think that the array is 1-based in `main` but (correctly) zero-based in `func`?

Comment: `i <= n` will access the array out of bounds on the last iteration.

Comment: Re "*Shouldn't `*(pArr+1)` print out `a[1]`?*", It does. /// The weird output is because you never assign anything to `a[0]`. You also attempt to set `a[n]`, which is undefined behaviour since the array only goes up to `n-1`.

Comment: ... and the following values `1 3 8 9` are one out step, with the `2` absent.

Comment: Tip: `func(&a[0], n);` could be written as `func(a, n);`. An array decays into a pointer to its first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`func` is correct, but you didn't populate `a` correctly.

Think of array indexes as offsets, which is to say how far they are from the start the array.

- The index/offset of the first element of an array is `0`.
- The index/offset of the second element of an array is `1`.
- ⋮
- The index/offset of the last element of an array with `n` elements is `n-1`.

So this is what you are building:

```
int a[5]
  0   1   2   3   4
+---+---+---+---+---+
| ? | 1 | 3 | 9 | 8 | 2
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

- You never assign a value to `a[0]`.
- You write a value beyond the end of the array. (Undefined behaviour!)
- Every value is in the wrong element (box).

Replace

```c
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)  // 1 (inclusive) to n (inclusive)
```

with

```c
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)   // 0 (inclusive) to n (exclusive)
```

Comment: Oh ok, I got where I was wrong. Thanks a lot for the help.